# Como passar uma String para um imageview

Tags: android

Tenho uma grande duvida, passei uma imagem de uma tela para outra e capturei sua *URL*, porém necessito transforma-lá para *Bitmap*, e exibi-lá em um *ImageView*.

Segue meu código:

```
public class ComentarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText comentario;
    private Button botaoSalvar;
    private ImageView fotoSelecionada;
    private String obID;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TextView texto;
    Context context;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comentar);

        comentario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_comentario);
        botaoSalvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_salvar);
        fotoSelecionada = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);



        //passando uma foto da galeria para a imageviewe


        Intent i = getIntent();
        obID = i.getStringExtra("imagem");

        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(obID, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        Drawable foto = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), decodedByte);
        fotoSelecionada.setImageBitmap(foto);
```

Alguma sugestão??

Comment: Essa URL dá acesso a uma imagem externa (de algum site)? Qual problema com seu código?

Comment: Você quis dizer URI? Com i de índio? Ou é URL mesmo?

Answer (score 0):

vc pode usar a biblioteca Picasso para carregar a imagem no ImageView.

importe a biblioteca:

> compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Se for na sua Activity por exemplo,  faça assim defina o caminho no ActivityResult após selecionar a foto da galeria :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

     Uri selectedPictureUri = data.getData();
     String picturePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
     loadIntoImageView(picturePath);
}

public void loadIntoImageView(String path){
     Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(path)
                    .into(imageView);
}
```